# Centering Text in Different Sized Columns using tabularX

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I need help centering horizontally the text in the dates/terms header in my table I created using tabularx. The text in the first column shouldn't be centered. I've tried multiple ways, but every way I try I either lose the two different column spacings and all columns end up as the same width or I end up with empty space to the right of the table (though the table should fill the entire width of text). Also, I can't seem to figure out why some of the vertical lines are darker than others. If you could help with that, too, much appreciated. Thank you for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}



\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize=5.5\hsize}X}


\begin{center}
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| b | s | s | s | s | s | s | s | s | s | s | s |}

\cline{2-12}
\multicolumn{1}{b|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{s|}{2018} & \multicolumn{3}{s|}{2019} & \multicolumn{3}{s|}{2020} & \multicolumn{3}{s|}{2021} & \multicolumn{1}{s|}{2022} \\
\cline{2-12}
\multicolumn{1}{b|}{} &  Fall & Spr & Sum &  Fall & Spr & Sum &  Fall & Spr & Sum &  Fall & Spr \\

\hline
 asdfasdfasdf   & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}  &\cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}  & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}  &\cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}  &\cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}  &\cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}  &  & & &  &  \\
 \cline{1-1}
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}  &  &  & & &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{1-1}
  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsf & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}  & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}   & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}   &  &  &  & &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{1-1}
 asdfasdfasdasdfasdfadsfasdff &  & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}  & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}  & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}  & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}  & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.4,0.8}   &  &  & &  &  \\
 \cline{1-1}
 asdfasasdfadsfasdfdfasdf  & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.8,0.4,0.3} & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.8,0.4,0.3} & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.8,0.4,0.3} & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.8,0.4,0.3} & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.8,0.4,0.3} & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.8,0.4,0.3} &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{1-1}
 asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.8,0.4,0.3} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & &  \\
 \cline{1-1}
 asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfafds &  & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.8,0.4,0.3} & &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\

\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I think you've misunderstood how one calculates the coefficients. The large `X` column (1st column) should be approximately how many times a small one?

Comment: Thanks for the response. About six times larger than a single small column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that works. You should keep in mind that, in case of `X` columns of different widths (with `\hsize=some coefficient \hsize`), the total of the coefficients has to be equal to the total number of `X` type columns;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array}\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.4,0.8}
\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{0.8,0.4,0.3}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=0.7\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize= 4.3\hsize\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| b|*{11}{s|}}
\cline{2-12}
\multicolumn{1}{b|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2018} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{2019} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{2020} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{2021} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2022} \\
\cline{2-12}
\multicolumn{1}{b|}{} & Fall & Spr & Sum & Fall & Spr & Sum & Fall & Spr & Sum & Fall & Spr \\
\hline
 asdfasdfasdf & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{myblue}} &\cellcolor{myblue} & \cellcolor{myblue} &\cellcolor{myblue}&\cellcolor{myblue} &\cellcolor{myblue} & & & & & \\
 \cline{1-1}
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{myblue}} & & & & & & & & & & \\
\cline{1-1}
  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsf & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{myblue}} & \cellcolor{myblue} & \cellcolor{myblue} & & & & & & & & \\
\cline{1-1}
 asdfasdfasdasdfasdfadsfasdff & & \cellcolor{myblue} & \cellcolor{myblue} & \cellcolor{myblue} & \cellcolor{myblue} & \cellcolor{myblue} & & & & & \\
 \cline{1-1}
 asdfasasdfadsfasdfdfasdf & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{myred}} & \cellcolor{myred} & \cellcolor{myred} & \cellcolor{myred} & \cellcolor{myred} & \cellcolor{myred} & & & & & \\
 \cline{1-1}
 asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{myred}} & & & & & & & & & & \\
 \cline{1-1}
 asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfafds & & \cellcolor{myred} & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]